# Error while trying to run Terraform Plan from VS Code

Tags: azure, powershell, terraform

I am trying to login to Azure from VS Code so that i can run Terraform scripts.
So i created a SP by following the below commands.

```
$azureAplicationId ="Azure AD Application Id"  
$azureTenantId= "Your Tenant Id"  
$azurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString "strong password" -AsPlainText -Force  
$psCred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($azureAplicationId , $azurePassword)  
Add-AzAccount -Credential $psCred -TenantId $azureTenantId  -ServicePrincipal   `enter code here`
```

After running the Add-AzAccount it displays me the Account Name, Subscription Name, Tenant ID and Environment.

But when i now try to run terraform plan from my VS Code so that i can check what all things will be deployed in my azure environment, it throws me this error below :

```
Error: Error building account: Error getting authenticated object ID: Error parsing json result from 
the Azure CLI: Error waiting for the Azure CLI: exit status 1: AADSTS50076: Due to a configuration 
change made by your administrator, or because you moved to a new location, you must use multi-factor 
authentication to access '00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000'.
Trace ID: 19a89f14-0138-4fbd-8d67-5f30c95e5701
Correlation ID: 7d80e2b1-49cc-4f42-9010-401e4453d13e
Timestamp: 2021-02-05 16:39:03Z
```

I have also tried logging in by typing Login-AzAccount and logged in using Multi Factor Auth, but still i see the above error.
Any reason why i am still getting the error while trying to run Terraform Plan even though i am logged in to Azure from my VS Code

Comment: I actually never tried to login using Az-Powershell when using Terraform. Can you try with az CLI `az login`?

Comment: Yah i tried with azcli and that helped. Someone told me that Powershell login is not yet supported it seems for Terraform

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in the comment:

You need to use Azure CLI and run `az login` first. Az-Powershell is not being used by Terraform under the hood.